# Pandas: How to read a "non-flat" csv with multiple headers?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I need to parse a large number of `csv` files to populate a database. The format of the csv file is confusing. Here is a simplified demo of the file then I'll comment on the content below:

|  | **A** | **B** | **C** | **D** | **E** | **F** | **G** | **H** | **I** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | `ll` |  |  |  |  | 0 | 10 | 4.9 | 50 |
| **2** | `hl` |  |  |  |  | 2 | 20 | 6.1 | 60 |
| **3** | `unit` |  |  |  |  | km/s | second | V | second |
| **4** | `param` | *SN* | *part_no* | *date* | *passfail* | *param01* | *param02* | *param03* | *param04* |
| **5** |  | ABC11 | p1 | 1/1/2020 | pass | 1 | 11 | 5 | 54 |
| **6** |  | ABC22 | p1 | 1/1/2020 | pass | 1.5 | 15 | 5.5 | 56 |
| **7** |  | ABC33 | p2 | 1/3/2020 | fail | 6 | 30 | 3 | 57 |

I need to create a datadataframe(s) to allow selects based on the following regions:

1. `csv[A1:H4]` is considered the header part of the file.
2. `csv[A1:A4]` are names for `csv[F1:I43]`. So , `['ll', 'hl', 'unit', 'param']` are names for rows: 1, 2,  3, 4 starting at `col[F]`.
3. `csv[B4:E7]`:  is a summary region for the rest for the columns.
4. `csv[F4:I7]`: is the data details to actually be examined against `ll` (or 'low limit'), and `hl` (or 'high limit').

Using `Pandas`, what is the most effective way to read such a file (in light of the definitions above)?

**Disclaimer:** My question may come across as "Opinion-based", I don't think so. I don't know what are the best practices when it comes to such files.

---

**Sample CSV**

Here is the CSV I'm using to model my code as requested in the comments. One thing makes my life easier, is that I bring row# 4 to the top early on.

```
ll,,,,,0,10,4.9,50
hl,,,,,2,20,6.1,60
unit,,,,,km/s,second,V,second
param,SN,part_no,date,passfail,param01,param02,param03,param04
,ABC11,p1,1/1/2020,pass,1,11,5,54
,ABC22,p1,1/1/2020,pass,1.5,15,5.5,56
,ABC33,p2,1/3/2020,fail,6,30,3,57
```

Comment: In addition to the table, can you post an example CSV at the end of the post?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to extract different tables in excel sheet using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69255564/how-to-extract-different-tables-in-excel-sheet-using-python)

Comment: I believe you meant I4 and not I43 ?  If your data is so specific, then is it possible to just read in and then usign .loc[] to extract the portion, transform it and fit it back as a Dataframe table that you need ?

Comment: @RaymondToh, not exactly. One major difference is the size of the file I'm working with, and the number of files I have to process. I'm hoping for a solution that reads the content in one manageable dataframe.

Comment: @EBDS good catch, but it's actually `I3`

Comment: @mbadawi23 Is your position fixed as you have described ?  eg csv[A1:H4] ... do you mean that it's always this position ?  Or you just giving an idea how the format looks like ?  Are all the postion fixed ?  csv[F1:I4], csv[B4:E7], csv[F4:I7].... ?

Comment: @EBDS, positions are not fixed. By that I mean each region may have different number of columns. The last row of the header is an argument that I receive (row 4 in this case). By the way... region# 1 should be [A1:I4].

Comment: @mbadawi23 That's the problem I kind of suspected.  If there are no markers, how would one be able to know how "large' the table is ?  There must be a way to identify the region.  I think that's something to think about first.  Once that is out of the way, the algo to extract, I believe, could be straight forward.  So could there be any pattern ?

Comment: @EBDS, the regions or pre-defined by arguments. For instance, I'd have a list for col names such as `summary_cols=['sn','part_no','date','pass_fail']`. The rest of the columns can be assumed to be all in the detail region.

Comment: @mbadawi23 I just give it a try in the answer below.  I'm not sure if I understant fully but just see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(d),nrows=3, header=None,index_col=0).dropna(how='all',axis=1).T
df2 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(d),skiprows=3 ).drop(labels='param',axis=1)
df1
df2
```

Output

```
    ll  hl  unit
5   0   2   km/s
6   10  20  second
7   4.9 6.1 V
8   50  60  second

    SN      part_no date passfail param01 param02 param03 param04
0   ABC11   p1      1/1/2020 pass 1.0     11      5.0     54
1   ABC22   p1      1/1/2020 pass 1.5     15      5.5     56
2   ABC33   p2      1/3/2020 fail 6.0     30      3.0     57
```

Comment: How would you corelate between the param cols in df2 and the rest of their data in df1?

Comment: @mbadawi23 What do you mean by correlation ?  Are you trying to align the 2 tables ?  I'm not sure what correlating means.  If you trying to align the tables, may be you could count the number of columns before and after, then you know how to align them. len(df1.columns)