# How to extract the table in excel using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I have  excel sheet having one sheet with 4 tables they are placed randomly. Out of the four tables, three tables have column name, except for one. Each table has 4 to 5 rows and 4 to 5 columns. How to extract all the tables without doing hard coding using Python. All tables are separated by some space.

Comment: Please add the sample tables, so people can reproduce them and help you more easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this previous question

> `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69255564/how-to-extract-different-tables-in-excel-sheet-using-python`

help? The example code that can be adapted to just print all tables in all sheets. It does also use pandas.